# Disqus Read-Only Comments

Tags: javascript, php, html, single-sign-on, disqus

I am using [Disqus Comments](http://disqus.com) with JavaScript Embed Code and PHP Single Sign-On on a webpage of mine. I want to make it so that users who are not logged in can only *view* comments, but not *actually comment*. So how can I embed view-only disqus comments? Thanks!

I really need to do this in a programmatic way, via PHP if possible. So if `$readonly` is true, the comments need to be view only. If it is false, the comment box needs to be enabled. Unfortunately there really isn't anything else I can do. Bounty Started.

When I refer to *logging in*, I am implying *logging in on my own website*, not on Disqus.

Comment: You also (per a comment of yours on an answer below), want to **allow people who are logged in to comment**, and **block people from logging in**. You should [edit] your question to clarify all your requirements.

Comment: @TRiG When I say _logging in_ I mean on my own website, not on disqus.

Comment: I can't answer the exact question and parameters laid out, but I have a suggestion: Turn on pre-moderation (Disqus admin > Settings > General page) then use Disqus whitelisting to automatically approve all of your own website users.  You can use the Disqus API (via PHP) to automatically post your site users to the Disqus whitelist. The only problem: users *could* still log in via Disqus to comment, but those comments won't appear - they'll go into moderation where you can ignore/delete them.

Comment: @GrantGibson this should be an answer, seems the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable guest commenting in the Disqus Admin -> Settings page

When its turned on, comments can be read but a login via Disqus, Google, Facebook or Twitter is required to leave a comment.

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: This isn't a solution because at any given time I want logged-in users to be able to comment via Disqus SSO, but I don't want users to be able to log in with Disqus.

Comment: why downvote? He gaved an answer for your question.. You should have been more specific in your question..

Answer (score 1):

I originally put this forward as a comment, but I think it's as close to an answer as you might get.

1. Turn on pre-moderation (Disqus admin > Settings > General page)
2. Then use Disqus whitelisting to automatically approve all of your *own* website users.
3. Use the Disqus API (e.g. via PHP) to automatically post *your* site users to the Disqus whitelist. See [Disqus whitelist API add](http://disqus.com/api/docs/whitelists/add/).

Users *could* still log in via Disqus to try to comment, but those comments won't appear on your site - they'll go into the moderation queue where you can ignore/delete them without them becoming public.

You could also add a message above the Disqus comment area telling people the rules of your site so they don't make the mistake of using the Disqus sign in option.

Comment: This is a great idea, however there doesn't appear to be a way to pre-approve site users (create SSO accounts for them without them being online). Whitelisting works, but only if the user already has an SSO account on disqus, created with an embedded front end snippet. Do you know of any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is. Every DOM-manipulation (e.g. triggered by an php script) is outwitable through modern browser's web page inspectors.

That's why I think, you have to implement your own comment system or have a look at the given [API features of disqus](https://disqus.com/api/docs/).